# using python to extract data from excel

Tags: python, excel, database

Hi I have a python program that will read data value from an excel file and extract specific data value and create a new excel with the extracted data value.
the excel file that python reads contains 3 columns 1- time, 2-Elapsed Time, and 3-Duct temp. [image]

the duct temperature is stored in this file as

`['duct1 temperature', [25.000882991454244, 25.002648974362724, 25.00387452337855, 25.004724896765367, 25.00531481876751, 25.005723932326624, . . . . .]]`
This is all in 1 cell (column 3)

each number is a node, so node 1 is extracted as  `25.000882991454244`
and node 2 is extracted as `25.002648974362724`

so the program works fine but I have some issues.
1- is that if I say I want 512 values it gives me an error

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ColumnExtractor.py", line 126, in <module>
    main(0, None)
  File "ColumnExtractor.py", line 114, in main
    timeData, data = readFile(directory, fileName)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object```

2- is that I can only extract each value at a time. so if I wanted to extract the 512 values I will have to do it manually and that will take a long time. 

so my question is is there any way to adjust this to extract every data value in the original file and store them in their each own column in the new excel file?
````

What is the file directory? /Users/jack/Downloads/1copy/untitledfolder
What would you like the new file to be called? results

How many values would you like to take? 4

Duct_temp_values.csv

Which node number to read? 3
Which column is the data in? 3
What would you like the first column to be called? temp
What would you like the final column to be called? time
Which node number to read? 1
Which column is the data in? 3
What would you like the first column to be called? temp2
What would you like the final column to be called? time
Which node number to read? 4
Which column is the data in? 3
What would you like the first column to be called? temp3
What would you like the final column to be called? time
Which node number to read? 5
Which column is the data in? 3
What would you like the first column to be called? temp4
What would you like the final column to be called? time ```

orignal file
[image]

results
[image]
the code it self is

```
import os
import csv
import xlwt


def getInputs():
    directoryFound = False
    csvFileNames = []
    convertedDir = ""

    while not directoryFound:
        convertedDir = ""
        folderDir = input("What is the file directory? ")

        for char in folderDir:
            if char == "\\":
                convertedDir += "/"
            else:
                convertedDir += char

        try:
            openFolder = os.listdir(convertedDir)

            for file in openFolder:
                if file[-3:] == "csv":
                    directoryFound = True

                    csvFileNames.append(file)
            
        except:
            print("That directory doesn't exist.\n")


    long = False

    while not long:
        output = input("What would you like the new file to be called? ")

        if len(output) > 0:
            long = True
            
            return output, csvFileNames, convertedDir


def readFile(directory, fileName):
    found = False
    
    while not found:
        try:
            file = open(f"{directory}/{fileName}", "r")
            
            found = True
            reader = csv.reader(file)

            data = []
            timeData = []

            lineNumber = 0
            
            for line in reader:
                if lineNumber % 2 == 1:
                    data.append(line)

                lineNumber += 1

            file.close()

            column = int(input("Which node number to read? "))
            columnWithData = int(input("Which column is the data in? "))

            exportArray = []

            for i, dataRow in enumerate(data):
                timeData.append(dataRow[0])
                mainData = dataRow[-1].split("[")[-1]

                dataArray = mainData.split(" ")

                for i, point in enumerate(dataArray):
                    newPoint = ""

                    for char in point:
                        if char != "," and char != "'" and char != "[" and char != "]":
                            newPoint += char

                    dataArray[i] = newPoint

                exportArray.append(dataArray[column - 1])

            firstName = input("What would you like the first column to be called? ")
            secondName = input("What would you like the final column to be called? ")

            return [secondName] + timeData, [firstName] + exportArray 
        except:
            print("Couldn't find a file with that name.\n")


def main(incr, openedBook):
    book = openedBook

    if not openedBook:
        book = xlwt.Workbook()
    
    output, csvFile, directory = getInputs()
    
    for fileName in csvFile:
        if "junction" not in fileName.lower():
            number = int(input("\nHow many values would you like to take? "))

            print("\n" + fileName, "\n")
            sheet = book.add_sheet(fileName)

            for j in range(number):
                timeData, data = readFile(directory, fileName)

                for i, value in enumerate(data):
                    if j == 0:
                        sheet.write(i, number, timeData[i])

                    sheet.write(i, j, value)

    book.save(f"{output}.xls")
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(0, None)
```

Comment: Try looking at [Using Python to Parse Spreadsheet Data](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-python-parse-spreadsheet-data/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. Mine actually works. I just need help with 2 issues just to make it perfect.